# When is it appropriate to use blank final variables?

Tags: java, final

I was looking at another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345061/why-must-a-final-variable-be-initialized-before-constructor-completes) about final variables and noticed that you can declare final variables without initializing them (a [blank final](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29#Blank_final) variable). Is there a reason it is desirable to do this, and when is it advantageous?

Comment: pretty much never. blank finals do nothing. they are variables which can never have any meaningful value ever. any java compiler worth its salt will give you a warning and/or error.

Comment: This can be useful when you want to initialize it in the constructor (based on some constructor parameters).

Comment: Final is final.. if you try to do 

    final int a = 2;
    a = 3;

it will throw an error

Comment: @sshannin declaration of a final and initialization in the constructor isn't a blank final, it's a declaration and initialization of a final variable.

Comment: @Hans that's exactly the definition of a blank final.

Comment: @Hans [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4): "A *blank* `final` is a `final` variable whose declaration lacks an initializer."

Comment: Wikipedia agrees with Marko and asslias - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java)#Blank_final

Comment: And so does the JLS - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/defAssign.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is useful to create immutable objects:

```
public class Bla {
    private final Color color;

    public Bla(Color c) {this.color = c};

}
```

Bla is immutable (once created, it can't change because color is final).
But you can still create various Blas by constructing them with various colors.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598245/immutable-in-java) for example.

**EDIT**

Maybe worth adding that a "blank final" has a very specific meaning in Java, which seems to have created some confusion in the comments - cf the [Java Language Specification 4.12.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4):

> A blank final is a final variable whose declaration lacks an initializer.

You then must assign that blank final variable in a constructor.

Comment: There I was thinking I was right in saying you can't do this. :) I did not know this. +1

Answer (score 5):

The final property of class must have a value assigned before object is created. So the last point where you can assign value to them is constructor.

This is used often for [immutable objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html).

```
 public class Foo {

  private final Bar bar;

  public Foo(Bar bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }

  public Bar getBar() {
   return new Bar(bar);
 } 
}
```

[What wiki says about it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29#Blank_final)

[Defensive copying.](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=15)

Comment: Yep.  This is what a "blank final" refers to, according to the Wikipedia citation.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, I did not realized that wiki describe it. I have added a ref to Wiki but, your "blank final" shows that Wiki is not the best place to gain knowledge. ;-).

Comment: Wait, what?  The accepted answer to the question that the OP linked included a Wikipedia link, which had a citation which agrees with your answer.

Comment: I thought that blank final is not a official naming, but as assylias quoted the not itializated final fields are called blank final.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this when you do not known what the value will be prior to the instrumentation of a Object, it just needs to have a value assigned in its constructor.

This is how you make [immutable objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html) and it is used in the builder pattern.

```
class Builder{
    final BuilderContext context;

    private Builder(BuilderContext context){
        this.context=context;
    }       

    public static Builder New(){
        return new Builder(new BuilderContext());
    }
```

Comment: The compiler _will_ complain about `new` as a method name.

Comment: Shouldn't the New() method be declared static? @JohnKane

Answer (score 1):

Blank final variables must be assigned "somewhere" in the constructor. A rather constructed example:

```
public class Test {
    final int sign;
    public Test(String upDown) {
        if (upDown.equals("up")) {
            sign = +1;
        } else {
            sign = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One case could be when you have a field which you want to declare final, but whose assignment may throw an exception and you want to be able to take action if that happens:

```
class A {
  final URLConnection conn;
  A(String url) {
    try {
      this.conn = new URL(url).openConnection();
    } catch (IOException | MalformedURLException e) {
      // Maybe this isn't fatal, so just handle the Exception
      // here and move on happily
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a blank final variable inside a method to show that all code paths which use the variable assign that variable exactly once (or throw an exception). Java compilers will guarantee that a blank final variable is assigned before it is used.

Example code inside some method:

```
  final Foo foo;
  if (condition1()) {
    foo = makeFoo(1);
  } else if (condition2()) {
    throw new BarException();
  } else {
    foo = makeFoo(-1);
  }
  ...
  blahBlahBlah(foo);
```

Using blank final variables tells the next reader of the code that the compiler guarantees that someone assigned foo before calling blahBlahBlah(foo).

The question asks about "blank final *variables*". Discussion of "blank final *fields*" is a different discussion, and interesting in its own right.

Answer (score 0):

> noticed that you can declare `final` variables without initializing them

You have to initialize it later (for example in the constructor) so it wont stay empty.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29#Final_variables)

The blank final, which was introduced in Java 1.1, is a final variable whose declaration lacks an initializer.  A blank final can only be assigned once and must be unassigned when an assignment occurs. In order to do this, a Java compiler runs a flow analysis to ensure that, for every assignment to a blank final variable, the variable is definitely unassigned before the assignment; otherwise a compile-time error occurs.

In general, a Java compiler will ensure that the blank final is not used until it is assigned a value and that once assigned a value, the now final variable cannot be reassigned another value.

Answer (score 0):

I find them very useful for methods that derive a state.  It provides a clean execution path and makes sure the state variable is assigned once and only once.  For example:

```
public boolean isEdible() {
    final boolean edible;

    if (vegetable) {
        edible = true;
    } else if (animal) {
        if (vegetarian) {
            edible = false;
        } else {
            edible = true;
        } 
    }
    System.out.println("Is edible: " + edible);
    return edible;
}
```