# How are variables in Java called that are set once but never again and are not final?

Tags: java

I have several variables I need to set only once but never again after starting the application, such as SCREEN_WIDTH, ARRAY_X_LENGTH, TIME_APP_STARTED etc.

I do not declare these final because the software will decide what value to assign to them, not me manually. I capitalize the words though so that I can see that no other code will assign any value to it, only 1.

Is this a bad programming practice, and if yes, what should I do, I usually just have a file containing all these ''final'' variables and my flags, I do not like storing them locally.

Comment: You can actually use `final` and initialize them later, `final` just means they can be initialized _once_ you don't have to do it manually.

Comment: *the software will decide what value to assign to them* - how?

Comment: Having a final variable doesn't mean the value has to be a compile time constant. It can be passed as a constructor parameter *later*

Comment: *I capitalize the words though so that I can see that no other code will assign any value to it* - Yes, this is bad. This is just *your* convention. You cannot prevent it from happening

Comment: declare final SCREEN_WIDTH, ARRAY_X_LENGTH, TIME_APP_STARTED. once application started assign it once. final variables assignment is allowed once

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is it appropriate to use blank final variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345747/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-blank-final-variables)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could assign values to it while the program is running. This answers the question. And what would you call a variable you assign values to multiple times, but rarely change?

Comment: What is `rarely` that is a very generic statement.  Sounds like just a variable to me.

Comment: There is no categorization or class of such variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class myClass{
    final int screenWidth;
    final int arrayXLength;
    final int timeAppStarted;

    public myClass(){
        screenWidth = getScreenWidth();
        arrayXLength = arrayX.length;
        timeAppStarted = getTime();
    }
}
```

Nothing wrong with that - you can just assign them the proper values in your constructor.

Note: These will be assigned a default value so you may want to check whether a proper assignment has been made. You can likewise declare as Integer instead of the primitive data type int.

Comment: really? `final int SCREEN_WIDTH = null;`- 1) `null` cannot be assigned to `int` 2) if it could (e.g assuming `Integer` instead of `int`), this would never be allowed to be changed later on, neither inside the constructor

Comment: Woops youre right. Fixed it ;-).

Comment: So if I declared `final int SCREEN_WIDTH;` and called its value what would it return, a 0 or a null?

Comment: It will return zero as undeclared primitive data types have default values associated with them. To have a null value it must be for an object. To get around this however, you could declare final Integer SCREEN_WIDTH; which would have the effect you are looking for. You are effectively not initializing the variable when you do this.

Comment: Thank you and sorry that this question is a duplicate. I actually read that related question before but didn't know it was related because I thought my values weren't considered `final`

Comment: Using all capitals for instance fields violates the commonly accepted Java coding standards.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to label those variable as `final`. the `final` keyword in Java means that the variable can only be initialized once after the application starts.

Note that if you aren't initializing your `final` variable the moment you're declaring it, then the only places you can initialize them in your code is in static blocks, instance-initializer blocks, or constructors.

Comment: it's a bit more complicated... the code that can initialize such variables is very restricted (like inside constructor or (static) initializer).

Comment: yeah, I'll edit my answer to make note of that.