# Java switch statement (why is this illegal?)

Tags: java, switch-statement

```
        final int a=2;
        final int b;
        b=3;
        
        switch(num){
            case a : // Legal
            case b : //Illegal
        }
```

**case a** is **Legal** but **case b** is **Illegal**.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: You can't reassign a final variable. Either assign a number to b or make it NOT final.

Comment: What is the compile error here?

Comment: You can only reassign final variables in a constructor. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11345841/12302982

Comment: @IgorFlakiewicz - Please provide a reference to your statement.

Comment: Notice that `b` is not initialized. We aren't changing its value in `b=3` - it's the initialization. And this is legal. Problem here is that the `switch` does not know about that. Roughly it requires labels to look like `final x = ....`.

Comment: Found a link to a decent older answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3827424/12302982

Comment: Reassigning local variables when they are `final` is indeed illegal. But the thing is that `b` is not reassigned – it is only assigned. [Here is an example](https://ideone.com/gCSOXt) which shows that using separate statements for *declaring* a `final` variable and *assigning* it, is perfectly fine.

Comment: My Eclipse does not complaint about the assignment to `b`. It does complaint about using `b` as case label: *case expressions must be constant expressions*.

Comment: So it kind of seems like this is a case of the compiler showing it's very focused nature. It only checks to see if the value is initialized in the same line to determine it as a constant. It won't check other lines to see if it's a constant _eventually_ since that might require checking hundreds of lines of code before it could do a check on this value. That would be a potentially time intense operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`switch` statement requires constant expression case labels.

While `b` is a constant after the code executed (so the `final` works), it is not a constant expression in the meaning of JLS : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28